Why can't I access $.Release.Name from a template helper?
I'm not getting something about Helm template variable resolution.
The following template helper function won't work.
(Note: bar is a subchart of foo in this example.)
{{/*
Create labels for component given by dict 
*/}}
{{- define "foo.makeLabels" -}}
{{- $new := dict "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" "Helm"  -}}
{{- $_ := set $new "meta.helm.sh/release-name" $.Release.Name -}}
{{- range $key, $val := . }}
{{-   $_ := set $new (print "app.kubernetes.io/" $key) $val }}
{{- end -}}
{{- toYaml $new }}
{{- end -}}

... when I try to invoke it as such:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount 
{{- $labels := (include "foo.makeLabels" (dict "name" .Values.foo.namespace "component" .Values.bar.name )) }}
{{- with .Values }} 
metadata:
  name: {{ print .foo.namespace "-" .bar.name }}
  namespace: {{ .foo.namespace }}
  labels:
{{- $labels | nindent 4 }}
{{- end -}}

The resulting error claims $Release is nil:
$ helm install foo . -n foo --create-namespace  --dry-run=server 
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: foo-log-server/templates/bar/serviceaccount.yaml:4:16: executing "foo-log-server/templates/bar/serviceaccount.yaml" at <include "foo.makeLabels" (dict "name" .foo.namespace "component" .bar.name>: error calling include: template: foo-log-server/templates/_helpers.tpl:6:48: executing "foo.makeLabels" at <$.Release.Name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.Name

..but when I use $.Release.Name directly in the invoking template, no problem!
(I know, the helper isn't in the best shape right now, and I'm sure you have good suggestions for the rest of it, but I was hoping to resolve this first.)
Shouldn't the use of $ resolve to the global context, which should be available everywhere? Or have I managed to override something?

$ appears to refer to the value . had outside of any with or range blocks that rebind it.  In the context of the helper template, though, that's the template parameter and not necessarily the "global" value of $.
At the top level, you're expecting to see $ evaluate to the global Helm object.
{{- $d := dict "foo" "bar" }}
{{- with $d }}
atRoot:
  dot: {{ keys . }}
  #    [foo]
  dollars: {{ keys $ }}
  #        [Files Release Capabilities Values Subcharts Template Chart]
{{- end }}

But experimentally if we put this into a helper template, we can see that $ evaluates to the parameter now.
{{- define "dollars" -}}
dot: {{ keys . }}
dollars: {{ keys $ }}
{{ end -}}

included:
{{ include "dollars" $d | indent 2 }}
# dot: [foo]
# dollars: [foo]

The Go text/template documentation only says

When execution begins, $ is set to the data argument passed to Execute, that is, to the starting value of dot.

One place to look is the implementation of include in the Helm source, which calls
err := t.ExecuteTemplate(&buf, name, data)

So, in the language of that documentation, the include call has a new Execute call with a new initial value of dot that is the new $ value.
